# Chromecast video playback hangs forever after sometime

Tags: chromecast

When I cast a video from my website(erosnow.com) on TV, video buffers and hangs frequently(I am on a very good internet connection, so it can't be internet speed). While streaming throughout the day I saw the stream buffering around every 20-30min, as well as a few times where the video didn't resume. For some of the videos, the playback will freeze(start buffering on TV) at exact time(say 1:29 min) everytime  i play it. It will keep buffering for ever and still it will not resume. In some cases, it will unload the video with the following error in chromecast dev console :

> a.abc.com/hls/movie/7/104987/fulllength/66717933/3136/1049107_6671795_1280_720_192_2944_22.ts
>   200] media_player.js:22  [294.441s] [cast.player.core.QualityManager]
>   0: current=7606972.51 media_player.js:22  [294.473s]
>   [cast.player.api.Host] error: cast.player.api.ErrorCode.NETWORK/301Gb
>   @ media_player.js:22Eb.di @ media_player.js:22ib.log @
>   media_player.js:19Kb @ media_player.js:23L @ media_player.js:85k.uc @
>   media_player.js:145pc @ media_player.js:34oc.dispatchEvent @
>   media_player.js:33D.Yh @ media_player.js:39 media_player.js:22 
>   [294.500s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload

Everything was working perfectly fine before. This issue is happening since 2 weeks. Seems like some bug in chromecast media player. Anyone else experiencing this issue?﻿

Comment: No answer, but a workaround: when this occurs, if I manually skip playback ahead of the time index where the hang occurs, then *once playback begins* I rewind to *before the time index of the hang* it'll play fine, without hanging on the trouble time index. This works even when exiting and completely restarting the cast stream fails to resolve the issue (for me, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Go into Chrome Settings > Show Advanced Settings > Disable Hardware Acceleration > Restart Chrome

I found it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/34rexr/chrome_browser_tab_casting_freezes_video/) and this seems to work to many users, I hope it works on your end too.

You may also check [Google Cast Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/XGLJ_BeMYoI) for other options that might help.